# Use different dataframes to create new one with information (Scala Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have **one dataframe with games and three valoration for every game from different reviews, every valoration is traduced in another dataframe** as you can see:

```
Df_reviews
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|Game    | rev_1 | rev_2 | rev_3  |
+- ------+-------+-------+--------+
|CA      |XX+    | K2    | L1     |
|FT      |Z-     | K1+   | L3     |

Df_rev1
+----------+-------------+ 
| review_1 | Equivalence | 
+----------+-------------+
|XX+       | 9           |      
|Y         | 6           |
|Z-        | 3           |   

Df_rev2
+----------+-------------+
| review_2 | Equivalence | 
+----------+-------------+
|K2        | 7           |      
|K1+       | 6           |
|K3        | 10          | 

Df_rev3
+----------+-------------+
| review_3 | Equivalence | 
+----------+-------------+
|L3        | 10          |      
|L2        | 9           |
|L1        | 8           |
```

**I have to traduce it in a new dataframe with the valoration traduced and add a column with the second best valoration**, for this example would be:

```
Df_output
+--------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+
|Game    | rev_1_t | rev_2_t | rev_3_t  | second_best |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+
|CA      |  9      |  7      | 8        |     8       |
|FT      |  3      |  6      | 10       |     6       |
```

To traduce it, I am trying with a left join but I am so lost. How can I deal with this?

**####### Second Part ######**
How can I translate columns from one dataframe to others from another dataframe, joining with multiple columns vs one? for example:

```
Df_revuews
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|Game    | rev_1 | rev_2 | rev_3  |
+- ------+-------+-------+--------+
|CA      |XX+    | K2    | L1     |
|FT      |Z-     | K1+   | L3     |


Df_equiv
+--------+-------+
|Valorat | num   |
+- ------+-------+
|X       |3      |
|XX+     |5      |
|Z       |7      |
|Z-      |6      |
|K1+     |6      |
|K2      |4      |
|L1      |5      |
|L2      |6      |
|L3      |7      |

Output
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|Game    | rev_1 | rev_2 | rev_3  |
+- ------+-------+-------+--------+
|CA      |5      | 4     | 5      |
|FT      |6      | 6     | 7      |
```

I am doing this as you can see:

```
val joined = df_reviews
.join(df_equiv, df_reviews("rev_1") === df_equiv("num") && df_reviews("rev_2") === df_equiv("num")
&& df_reviews("rev_3") === df_equiv("num"), "left")
.select(df_reviews("Game"), 
        df_equiv("num").as("rev_1_t"), 
        df_equiv("num").as("rev_2_t"), 
        df_equiv("num").as("rev_3_t")
       )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some left joins and get the second highest column using `sort_array`:

```
val joined = df_reviews
    .join(df_rev1, df_reviews("rev_1") === df_rev1("review_1"), "left")
    .join(df_rev2, df_reviews("rev_2") === df_rev2("review_2"), "left")
    .join(df_rev3, df_reviews("rev_3") === df_rev3("review_3"), "left")
    .select(df_reviews("Game"), 
            df_rev1("Equivalence").as("rev_1_t"), 
            df_rev2("Equivalence").as("rev_2_t"), 
            df_rev3("Equivalence").as("rev_3_t")
           )

val array_sort_udf = udf((x: Seq[Int]) => x.sortBy(_ != null))

val result = joined.withColumn(
    "second_best",
    coalesce(
        array_sort_udf(
            array(col("rev_1_t").cast("int"), col("rev_2_t").cast("int"), col("rev_3_t").cast("int"))
        )(1),
        greatest(col("rev_1_t").cast("int"), col("rev_2_t").cast("int"), col("rev_3_t").cast("int"))
    )
)

result.show
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|Game|rev_1_t|rev_2_t|rev_3_t|second_best|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|  CA|      9|      7|      8|          8|
|  FT|      3|      6|     10|          6|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

For your second question:

```
val joined = df_reviews.as("r1")
    .join(df_equiv.as("e1"), expr("r1.rev_1 = e1.Valorat"), "left")
    .selectExpr("Game", "e1.num as rev_1", "rev_2", "rev_3")
    .as("r2")
    .join(df_equiv.as("e2"), expr("r2.rev_2 = e2.Valorat"), "left")
    .selectExpr("Game", "rev_1", "e2.num as rev_2", "rev_3")
    .as("r3")
    .join(df_equiv.as("e3"), expr("r3.rev_3 = e3.Valorat"), "left")
    .selectExpr("Game", "rev_1", "rev_2", "e3.num as rev_3")

joined.show
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|Game|rev_1|rev_2|rev_3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|  CA|    5|    4|    5|
|  FT|    6|    6|    7|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi mck! sorry for not answer before! I have been testing this, but could be a problem with this code. For example, if there is only one review and the other two are nulls, I always get in this case a null, because I am putting null in the greatest. Another problem could be if the greatest is for example in the three cases the same value, for example 9-9-9 I would get null too. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Hi @MLstudent, maybe you can try using `sort_array` and get the second element. See my edited answer?

Comment: Sorry mck for being late again. I would like to get it the value if there are for example 2 nulls and only one value.
I edited the post with a second question and how I am doing it, is a good way to do it?

Comment: Wow I think it is working! But in the sort_array, I am taking the second highest, for example 9 - 7 - 5 -> 7 but keeping that 9 is the highest but for this example I want that 5 will be the highest, how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, is not he highest, is the lowest but is like the most important value is 1, 2, 3 ... and in this way the most important is 10, 9, 8

Comment: Ok, don't know if you understood me. In this way the most important value is 1 then 2, 3 ... if we had an array with (01 - null - 02) I have to pick 02, always the second value, but with this code I pick 01.

Comment: I can't use array_sort even deleting the true / false argument

Comment: I am using 2.2.1. Is not valid array_sort¿

Comment: I tried, but in this way, for example if I have (null - null - 09) I would get 9999 because I am replacing nulls with 9999 and the second highest is 9999 :(

Comment: Try the edited UDF solution... hope it will work for you

Comment: data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<int> and I am passing array<String>

Comment: Storing ints as strings is a horrible practice... See edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, I stored as string because I am working with a example DF made with Seq. Now I think is working. I am going to test it again tonight! But for real, you are a genious and helped me a lot! Wish you the best because not all the people do this!